# How to get all the classname used inside the button from one class?

Tags: javascript

I have a button with multiple classname a, b and active.

```
<button class="a b active"></button>
```

I want to get the classname a & b only using active. I have used following code

```
document.querySelectorAll('.active')
```

I get

```
<button_ngcontent-c1="" class="a b active" ng-reflect-klass="0,0" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"></button>
```

I am not being able to get this class a and b.

Can anybody help?

Comment: You can use .className method to get all the classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` gives you a NodeList.

From that, spread that list into an array, and iterate over it to get the `className` property :

```js
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.active');

const els = [...nodeList];

for (let el of els) {
  console.log(el.className.split(' '));
}
```

```html
<button class="a b active"></button>
<button class="c d active"></button>
<button class="e f active"></button>
```